# no me funcio el autoplay en safari de mi iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

buen dia, tengo una pagina web que me reproduce una canción automatica con autoplay pero no me funciona si la abro desde un iPhone con el navegador safari, como hago para habilitar en safari para que deje reproducir el audio de forma automatica en el ihpone?.

"https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player"

```
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
//...
<ReactAudioPlayer
  src="my_audio_file.ogg"
  autoPlay
  controls
/>
```

Comment: Hace falta más información para poder determinar el problema. Has leído la [guía](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability) de uso para el atributo `autoplay`? Considera crear un [mcve] para tu pregunta. También es necesario que menciones las versiones de iOS y Safari que utilizas, etc. Haz clic en [edit] para agregar más detalles.

Comment: ya añadi el codigo que estoy utilizando